# How to detect Cortex-M33 chip running in secure vs non-secure state?

Tags: embedded, cortex-m

I've got an ARM Cortex-M33 chip I'm doing embedded development on and I'd like to be to able to check at runtime the current TrustZone security state of the CPU: secure vs non-secure.

I found the DSCSR (Debug Security Control and Status Register) has bit 16 CDS (Current domain Secure) which indicates the current security state of the processor but documentation says that this register is accessible only to the debugger.

Is there any way for software running on the Cortex-M33 to get the security state?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this code can be used to determine the state, correct me if I am wrong. However, the code executing it must be in privileged mode. Would be nice if non-privileged code also has a way to detect secure mode vs non-secure mode.

```
// Per DDI0553B Armv8-M Architecture Reference Manual 

// CPUID

// Privileged access permitted only. Unprivileged accesses generate a fault.
// 32-bit read-only register located at 0xE000ED00.
// Secure software can access the Non-secure version of this register
// via CPUID_NS located at 0xE002ED00.
// The location 0xE002ED00 is RES0 to software executing in Non-secure
// state and the debugger.

volatile uint32_t *cpuid_ns = (volatile uint32_t *) 0xE002ED00;

if (*cpuid_ns == 0) {
    puts("Running in non-secure state");
} else {
    puts("Running in secure state");
}
```

Comment: This is a pretty ugly hack BTW, surprised if there isn't a better way to do this...

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a better solution. Reading the Cortex-M33 TRM I found the follow sentence:

> For instructions and data, the SAU returns the security attribute that is
> associated with the address.
>
> For instructions, the attribute determines the allowable Security
> state of the processor when the instruction is executed. It can also
> identify whether code at a Secure address can be called from Non-secure
> state.

Based on my understanding, an Arm Cortex processor with security extensions determines the security state simply by examining the security attributes of the current program counter. In other words if the PC is within a secure address region then the CPU is in secure state, and if the PC is within a non-secure address region then the CPU is in the non-secure state.

**Someone please correct me if this wrong!**

Therefore we can utilize the test-target instruction on the program counter to determine what state we are currently running in since the test-target instruction returns the security state of an address.

```
#include "core_cm33.h"
#include "arm_cmse.h"

#define TT_SECURE_BIT_MASK 0x400000

static __inline__ __attribute__((always_inline)) void * get_pc(void)
{
    void *pc;
    asm("mov %0, pc" : "=r"(pc));
    return pc;
}

void func(void)
{
    if (cmse_TT(get_pc()).value & TT_SECURE_BIT_MASK) {
        // CPU is in secure state
    } else {
        // CPU is in non-secure state
    }
}
```

Example results:

```
// TT on the PC when PC is running code within a secure region
// Hex: 0x03cc0000
// Binary: 00000011 11001100 00000000 00000000
// Bit 22 is 1 indicating CPU is in secure state

// TT on the PC when PC is running code within a non-secure region
// Hex: 0x000c0000
// Binary: 00000000 00001100 00000000 00000000
// Bit 22 is 0 indicating CPU is in non-secure state
```